# Single image detection in ARToolkit

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, artoolkit

I am wondering if it is possible to use ARToolkit for **single image detection** in Android wrapper? For example: choose image from gallery or capture image with camera and then send bytes to ARToolkit for marker recognition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very much possible and I've done it already but in a little different way.

I have integrated ARToolkit library into the sample ARCore app(hello_ar_java) from the [github repo](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java) of ARCore, I used artoolkitx for image detection since it's detection speed is very fast.

In the hello_ar_java app, there's an openGL function onDrawFrame() which gets called on every frame change and here the frames that I receive from ARCore session update is converted into image(jpeg) files and written to the disk.

ARToolkit java wrapper has a method `arwStartRunning()` in [ARX_jni.java](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/blob/68245e9edfea9c86585fc29572f8a8a75e0df1bc/Source/ARXJ/ARXJProj/arxj/src/main/java/org/artoolkitx/arx/arxj/ARX_jni.java#L141) which accepts video configuration and camera parameters as method parameters.
 **Your task here is**, in the java wrapper there's a class `ARController.java`, write a method in this class to call the `arwStartRunning()` of `ARX_jni.java`

Eg.

```
 public boolean startRunning(String cfg) {
     if (!ARX_jni.arwStartRunning(cfg, null)) {
         Log.e(TAG, "StartRunning command failed.");
         return false;
     }
     Log.e(TAG, "StartRunning command passed.");
     return true;
 }
```

Now rebuild ARToolkit library and add the new **`arxj-release.aar`** file into your app.

From your android app code, call the startRunning() method by passing configurations as

```
String cfg = "-module=Image -width=" + imageWidth + " -height=" + imageHeight + " -image=" + imageAbsolutePath;

boolean runStatus = ARController.getInstance().startRunning(cfg);

if (runStatus) {
    if (!ARController.getInstance().captureAndUpdate()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ARController update call failed, skip going further.");
        return;
    } else Log.d(TAG, "vaib: ARController update call passed");

    for (int trackableUID : trackableUIDs) {
        float[] modelViewMatrix = new float[16];
        if (ARController.getInstance().queryTrackableVisibilityAndTransformation(trackableUID, modelViewMatrix)) {
            float[] projectionMatrix = ARController.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix(10.0f, 10000.0f);
            Log.e(TAG, "Trackable "+trackableUID +" is visible.");
            runOnUiThread(() -> showToast("Trackable "+trackableUID +" is visible."));

        } else Log.e(TAG, "Trackable "+trackableUID +" is not visible");
    }
} else Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start ARToolkit, config used : " + cfg);
```